# Sorting elements in a np.array using constrains

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, machine-learning

I want to sort a np.array in a certain order f.i. I have input array a:

```
a = np.array([[ 2,  2,  1,],
              [ 3,  3,  3,],
              [ 2,  3,  2,]])
```

and I want to get for the output:

```
b = np.array([[ 2,  3,  2,],
              [ 3,  1,  3,],
              [ 2,  3,  2,]])
```

as you may probably guess, the idea for this sorting is to make a *symmetry* in the array (and plus other stuff, which is not relevant here).

My issue is I'm doing just the random shuffle in order to sort the array:

```
iNumbers = 0
while !symmetry(a) and iNumbers != 3000:
      np.random.shuffle(a.flat)
      iNumbers += 1
```

where `symmetry` function is True if the arrangement of elements is matched the criteria.

So, I am looking for more efficient ways to sort arrays in order to pass my evaluation function.

Should I apply machine learning techniques to my issue?

Also, I'm looking for any suggestion, remark, idea or thought...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you have symmetry because your elements allow it (the right number of 3, 2 and 1 for symmetry to be possible). Assuming you take this into consideration what you're looking for is kind of radial sort. The following algorithm does this:

```
import numpy as np

def sortRadially(a):
    X, Y = np.indices(a.shape, dtype="float")
    c = int(a.shape[0]/2)
    d = np.sqrt((c-X)**2 + (c-Y)**2)
    fd = d.flatten()
    fX = X.flatten()
    fY = Y.flatten()
    argD = fd.argsort()
    nX = fX[argD].astype(int)
    nY = fY[argD].astype(int)
    fa = a.flatten()
    sa = a.copy()
    fa.sort()
    for i in range(nX.shape[0]):
        a[nX[i], nY[i]] = fa[i]
    return a

a = np.array([[ 2,  2,  1,],
              [ 3,  3,  3,],
              [ 2,  3,  2,]])

myown = np.random.randint(0, 100, (9, 9))

print("Your test:")
print(sortRadially(a))
print("")
print("My test:")
print(sortRadially(myown))
```

The result is this:

```
Your test:
[[3 2 3]
 [2 1 2]
 [3 2 3]]

My test:
[[97 95 91 78 60 73 84 92 98]
 [93 78 55 44 30 34 55 80 92]
 [84 45 22 15 10 17 23 44 88]
 [71 42 12  7  2  7 16 42 73]
 [69 28 10  2  0  1 10 28 66]
 [72 44 13  5  1  3 14 38 77]
 [87 49 19 14  8 19 24 52 91]
 [95 83 48 43 33 39 52 79 94]
 [98 94 83 73 67 71 91 96 99]]
```

I'm no specialist in sorting algorithms and there are probably faster ways to do this but it should certainly be faster than shuffling and waiting for the best.

The explanation to the algorithm is the following:

1. You get the coordinates of all cells (X, Y).
2. You calculate the    distance from all coordinates to center cell
   (in my algorithm I    assume the matrix is square with an odd size
   of row/col).
3. You sort    the distance and obtain the indexes (instead of distance
   values).
4. Apply the same sort for X and Y coordinates.
5. Sort your original  array.
6. Following the sorted cells and coordinates fill up the    array.
7. There's really no step 7), I just don't like leaving things at 6...

Comment: What with this data set [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]? I don't think that's covered by this method ;-)

Comment: @PaulPanzer True;) The example does not have anything to do with symmetry. That is just a natural consequence of the type of Sorting (if possible). In any case as a general note to anyone interested I assumed the center to be the smallest values. If the point is symmetry a sorting the other way around would also be possible. To do this just reverse the sorting done to distance (for example: `fd.argsort()[::-1][:n]`)).

Comment: How about this one then `[1] + 7 * [2] + [3]`? you will get the centre right, but one of the corners will be wrong no matter what direction you sort.

Comment: @PaulPanzer That one I'm not sure how you would expect symmetry. The only element without repetition must be at the center. In your example there is no way both 1 or 3 reflect to any side. But notice that this is just a quick deterministic solution for the problem. Other constraints could be inserted. For example no symmetry axis was specified so I assumed all of them must be respected. But why not solve only symmetries for X, or for Y, or a diagonal symmetry? I just gave the OP an head start, there are plenty of possible approaches to this problem.

Comment: You're right, I didn't see the top down symmetry still there is 4 x [1] + [2] + 4 x [3] then. I just think ordering and symmetry are really not the same thing here. On a 3x3 grid you may observe some overlap but the larger you go, the less lucky you'll be. But never mind, OP seems happy, so I suppose it's a good answer.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I agree, sort is not symmetry. As I mentioned in a previous comment the symmetry will only be a consequence. For example where you to replace 2 with 1 and the sorting 1, 2, 3 would no longer make sense. The constraint in this case would be to sort by number repetitions instead of the numbers themselves. But all of these constraints are added support to a more general purpose approach. I was not trying to make an algorithm to solve all possible situations, I was just trying to show a numerical way to do it. The challenge now is: adapt.

Comment: @PaulPanzer if you have a better solution, I'm all ears.

Comment: @Paddy trying to bait me, are we? Tell you what come up with a clear definition of what you're after and I might consider it ;-)